# Why are there identical method names in LWJGLs OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I can't find a really good example quickly looking through the javadoc, but why do the different versions (GL11, GL15, GL30, etc.) sometimes have the same methods? The javadoc also says that these methods "overload" the methods (they may refer to the 'original' methods).

EDIT
Overloading is not relevant in this context.

Comment: Are you asking what "method overloading" is? If so, Google It!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple versions of OpenGL, each one adding new functions and some deprecating old ones. The different GL classes correspond to each version (GL11 = OpenGL 1.1, GL15 = OpenGL 1.5, GL30 = OpenGL 3.0). I'm not very familiar with LWJGL, but it probably offers compile-time warnings for deprecated functions and only has the functions supported in that version.

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL

**EDIT**

To respond to the comments, one version is generally not "better" than another, it's just supporting a newer specification based on what you want the minimum spec for your program to be and what the user's machine supports.

Looking into LWJGL docs, each `GLXX` class does not support the entire API, just the functions that were added in that version of the specification. For example, [glActiveTexture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glActiveTexture) (Page lists "Core since version: 1.3") was added in OpenGL 1.3, so the function and all of it's parameters are included in the [GL13](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL13.html) class.

Another different example is the [GL_SRGB](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL21.html#GL_SRGB) constant in the GL21 class. OpenGL 2.1 added support for sRGB textures in the `glTexImageXD` class of functions, which is defined in `GL11` [here](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html).

If your machine supports OpenGL 2.1+, you'd be able to use GL_SRGB as an argument. Otherwise the function will give you an error. The same goes for newer formats added as part of newer specs. If you have OpenGL 4.3 support you'd be able to use `COMPRESSED_RGB8_PUNCHTHROUGH_ALPHA1_ETC2`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will not accept it now because maybe someone can give a specific example why one version's method is better than the other.

Comment: If you look at the OpenGL 2.0 and 4.5 specifications you will see that the same functions take different parameters; one example would be the texture functions - more image formats are available in subsequent OpenGL versions.

Comment: @DasEtwas I added a few specific examples with links to the LWJGL docs. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @RobertRouhani Very nice. Thanks.